# SwiftUI: Repeat animation forever with delay at the end, without autoreverse

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, swiftui-animation

I want to repeat an animation forever, without it to autoreverse, and with a delay/pause *between* the repetitions after the animation played.

I know there is a `.delay()` modifier, but it delays the beginning of the animation:

```
let ani = Animation.easeInOut.delay(1.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
```

In addition with the `.repeatForever` modifier, after the animation played it immediately jumps back to its beginning. But I want the last keyframe to remain visible on the screen for a short amount of time.

I’ve also tried it the other way around, adding a `.delay()` after the `.repeatForever` modifier, but without success (`delay` has no effect).

```
let ani = Animation.easeInOut.repeatForever(autoreverses: false).delay(1.0)
```

**How can I add a delay after the animation played?**

Comment: You can try using `GeometryEffect` for a key frame based animation https://swiftui-lab.com/swiftui-animations-part2/ Swiftui Animation by itself is not easy to synchronize.

Comment: Timing curve might do it too https://www.objc.io/blog/2019/09/26/swiftui-animation-timing-curves/